# In the Kafka/Zookeeper scenario, do the ordering nodes communicate to each other?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Considering a production scenario where I have two or more Ordering nodes (Kafka mode), each one on a different host, do the ordering nodes need to communicate each other in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Kafka-based orderer, the actual ordering nodes DO NOT directly communicate with each other.  All coordination is done via the Kafka cluster.  So each ordering service node just needs to be able to communicate with the Kafka cluster